# mypy error: property defined is read-only, Callable class had no attribute "setter"

Tags: python, mypy

I dont know why `mypy` is throwing errors at properties that are properly defined (unless I am mistaken).

Here is my code:

```py
from fs.sshfs import SSHFS


class SMS:
    _USER_DEFAULT: str = "xxx"
    _PASSWORD_DEFAULT: str = "xxx"
    _PORT_DEFAULT: int = 22

    def __init__(
        self,
        host: str,
        user: str = _USER_DEFAULT,
        password: str = _PASSWORD_DEFAULT,
        port: int = _PORT_DEFAULT,
    ):
        self._host: str = ""
        self._user: str = ""
        self._password: str = ""
        self._port: int = 0

        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.port = port

    @property
    def sshfs(self) -> SSHFS:
        return SSHFS(
            host=self.host, user=self.user, passwd=self.password, port=self.port
        )

    @property
    def host(self) -> str:
        return self._host

    @property
    def user(self) -> str:
        return self._user

    @property
    def password(self) -> str:
        return self._password

    @property
    def port(self) -> int:
        return self._port

    @host.setter
    def host(self, host: str) -> None:
        if not isinstance(host, str):
            raise TypeError("Host must be a string!")
        self._host = host

    @user.setter
    def user(self, user: str) -> None:
        if not isinstance(user, str):
            raise TypeError("User should be a string!")
        self._user = user

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password: str) -> None:
        if not isinstance(password, str):
            raise TypeError("Password must be a string!")
        self._password = password

    @port.setter
    def port(self, port: int) -> None:
        if not isinstance(port, int) or port < 21:
            raise TypeError("Port number must be an integer and above 20!")
        self._port = port
```

**To Reproduce**

```sh
mypy <the pasted code file>
```

Result:

```
mycodefile.py:55: error: Property "host" defined in "SMS" is read-only
mycodefile.py:56: error: Property "user" defined in "SMS" is read-only
mycodefile.py:57: error: Property "password" defined in "SMS" is read-only
mycodefile.py:58: error: Property "port" defined in "SMS" is read-only
mycodefile.py:117: error: Name "host" already defined on line 73
mycodefile.py:117: error: "Callable[[SMS], str]" has no attribute "setter"
mycodefile.py:135: error: Name "user" already defined on line 84
mycodefile.py:135: error: "Callable[[SMS], str]" has no attribute "setter"
mycodefile.py:153: error: Name "password" already defined on line 95
mycodefile.py:153: error: "Callable[[SMS], str]" has no attribute "setter"
mycodefile.py:171: error: Name "port" already defined on line 106
mycodefile.py:171: error: "Callable[[SMS], int]" has no attribute "setter"
Found 12 errors in 1 file (checked 5 source files)
```

**Environment**

- Mypy version used: `0.941`
- Python version used: `3.8.13`
- Operating system and version: macOS 12.2

I don't know how to fix those errors please help. As far as I know everything is well defined

Comment: With mypy 0.910 and python 3.9 your code raises the same mypy errors but putting each setter right after its property seems to fix the problem.

Comment: lol now after, as you said, I put each setter right after its property there is not errors wtf

Comment: It looks like a mypy bug. Maybe you should consider posting a bug report at https://github.com/python/mypy/issues

Comment: reported, thanks a lot for help! If you could post this as a solution and link to this bug  I will accept it ;)
https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12376

Comment: Actually a similar post has already been posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58121030/how-can-i-use-property-setters-and-make-mypy-happy and the bug is already known : https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1465 (dates back to 2016).